# The Language {xx}, of any string followed by another copy of the same string, is not Context Free. Using Pumping Lemma, through 13 cases.

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I write here the *Pumping Lemma for Context Free Languages* I refer:

For all context free languages $L$ there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}
\mid \forall z \in L$ with $\left | z \right | \ge k$, there exist
$uvwxy$ such that:

1. $z= uvwxy$,
2. $v$ and $x$ are not both $\epsilon$,
3. $\left | vwx \right | \le k$, and
4. $\forall i, uv^iwx^iy \in L$

---

And this is the Language I want to prove that is not Context Free:
in the following I'll write CF(L)=Context Free (Languages), PL=Pumping Lemma

$L = \left \{ xx \mid x \in \Sigma^* \right \}$, is not CF for any alphabet $\Sigma$ with at least two symbols.

*Proof* -

1. by contradiction using PL for CFL. Assume that $L$ is CF, so the PL holds for $L$.
2. Let $k$ be as given by the PL. Choose $z = a^kb^ka^kb^k$, so $z \in L$ and $|z| \ge k$ as required.
3. Let $u,v,w,x,y$ be as given by the PL, so $uvwxy = a^kb^ka^kb^k$, $v$ and $x$ are not both $\epsilon$, $|vwx| \le k$, and $\forall i$, $uv^iwx^iy \in L$.
4. Now consider how the substrings $v$ and $x$ fall within the string. Since $|vwx| \le k$, $v$ and $x$ cannot be widely separated, so we have these *13 cases*:

[image: lang_xx]

For **cases 1 through 5**, we can choose $i = 0$. Then the string $uv^0wx^0y$ is some $sa^kb^k$ where $|s| < 2k$. In this string the **last** symbol of the **first** half is an $a$, while the **last** symbol of the **second** half is a $b$. So $uv^0wx^0y \notin L$.

For **cases 9 through 13**, $i = 0$, the string $uv^0wx^0y$ is some $a^kb^ks$ where $|s| < 2k$. In this string the **first** symbol of the **first** half is an $a$, while the **first** symbol of the **second** half is $b$. So, again $uv^0wx^0y \notin L$.

For **cases 6,7,8**, $i=0$, the string $uv^0wx^0y$ is some $a^ksb^k$ where $|s| < 2k$. But such an $a^ksb^k$ can't be $rr$ for any $r$, because if $r$ starts with $k$ *a*s and ends with $k$ *b*s, we must have $|r| \ge 2k$ and so $|rr| \ge 4k$, while our $|a^ksb^k| < 4k$. So again, $uv^0wx^0y \notin L$.

5. In every case we have a contradiction, so by contradiction, $L$ is not a CFL. $\Box$

---

There are some parts I don't understand-
I consider *cases from 9 through 13*, where I think it is more evident my misunderstanding:

> For **cases 9 through 13**, $i = 0$, the string $uv^0wx^0y$ is some
>   $a^kb^ks$ where $|s| < 2k$. In this string the **first** symbol of the
>   **first** half is an $a$, while the **first** symbol of the **second** half is $b$. So, again $uv^0wx^0y \notin L$.

What is "this string"?

- Is it $a^kb^ks$? 
  If so, considering as first half $a^kb^k$, here the first symbol is $a$; and if the second half is $s$, since $v$ and $x$ must be not both $\epsilon$, $s$ must begin with $a$, but, why it is said $b$? Can you explain me better?
- Or is it $s$, and divide it in two parts?
  Here, the first symbol of the first half $s$ *must* be $a$, since $v$ and $x$ aren't both $\epsilon$, and the first symbol of the second half of $s$ is $b$.

(In analog way for cases 1 through 5, so if I understand the above, I understand also those ones).

And also in **cases 6,7,8**:

> For **cases 6,7,8**, $i=0$, the string $uv^0wx^0y$ is some $a^ksb^k$
>   where $|s| < 2k$. But such an $a^ksb^k$ can't be $rr$ for any $r$,
>   because if $r$ starts with $k$ *a*s and ends with $k$ *b*s, we must
>   have $|r| \ge 2k$ and so $|rr| \ge 4k$, while our $|a^ksb^k| < 4k$. So
>   again, $uv^0wx^0y \notin L$.

Here, I don't understand what it is said about $rr$.

Can you explain me better? Many many thanks for your patience, really!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases 9 through 13 :

"This string" is $uv^0wx^0y=a^kb^ks$. If "this string" is in $L$, it must have even length, so $s$ has even length too, say $2t$ for some integer $t$. The total length of "this string" is then $k+k+2t=2(k+t)$. Since $v$ and $x$ are not both empty, $uvwxy$ has length strictly greater than $uv^0wx^0y$, so "this string" has length $<4k$, and we deduce that $t<k$.

The first half of "this string" is made of the first $k+t$ symbols, so the first half is $a^kb^t$. As you can see, this first half starts with an $a$.
  The second half of "this string" is made of the last $k+t$ symbols, so the second half is $b^{k-t}s$. As you can see, this second half starts with a $b$.

For cases 6,7,8 : 
   In this case, "this string" is $uv^0wx^0y=a^ksb^k$. As above, $s$ must have even length, say $2t$ for some integer $t$. The total length of "this string" is then $k+k+2t=2(k+t)$. Note that $t<k$. Denote by $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{2t}$ the symbols in $s$.
   The first half of "this string" is made of the first $k+t$ symbols, so the first half is $a^ks_1s_2\ldots s_t$. As you can see, this first half starts with $a^k$.
  The second half of "this string" is made of the last $k+t$ symbols, so the second half is $s_{t+1}s_{t+2}\ldots s_{2t}b^k$. As you can see, this second half ends with $b^k$. 
    If "this string" is in $L$, the first half and the second half are in fact the same string, called $r$ in the text. Then $r$ must both start with $a^k$ and end with $b^k$, which forces $r$ to have length $\geq 2k$. This means that $uv^0wx^0y=rr$ has length $\geq 4k$. Since $v$ and $x$ are not both empty, $uvwxy$ has length strictly greater than $uv^0wx^0y$, and we deduce $4k>4k$ which is absurd.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't fully understand the last part: why forces $r$ to have length $\ge 2k$?

Comment: @JB-Franco well, as it says in the text, on the left of $r$ you have $k$ "$a$" symbols, on the right of $r$ you have $k$ "$b$" symbols. When you count, how many symbols does that make ?

Comment: If I understand $r = a^kb^k$, so $|r| = 2k$. why you include also the case $>$?

Comment: Because $r$ starts with $a^k$ and ends with $b^k$ but there's some other symbols in-between also : it's $r=a^k(...)b^k$ not just $r=a^kb^k$

Comment: Pardon for my difficulties. So, "this string" is $a^ksb^k$, the first half is $a^ks_1s_2 \ldots s_t$ and the second half is $s_{t+1}s_{t+2} \ldots s_{2t}b^k$. If it is true that $a^ksb^k \in L$, therefore it means that the first half and the second half must be the same, i.e. if $h_1 = a^ks_1s_2 \ldots s_t, h_2 = s_{t+1}s_{t+2} \ldots s_{2t}b^k$, each half must begin with $a^k$ and finish with $b^k$, so $rr = h_1b^ka^kh_2$, where $|h_1b^k| \ge 2k, |a^kh_2| \ge 2k$. Is it right?

Comment: @JB-Franco You are correct, except for the formula $rr=h_1b^ka^kh_2$. hat happens here is that the two halves must be the same $h_1=h_2=r$, so that "this string" is $h_1h_2=rr$.

Comment: In order that the two halves be the same, they must start with $a^k$ and finish with $b^k$, so the first half $h_1 = a^ks_1s_2 \ldots s_tb^k$ and the second half $h_2 = a^ks_{t+1}s_{t+2} \ldots s_{2t}b^k$, here $h_1 = h_2 = r$. Is it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56986/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-jb-franco).

Comment: So we have that $a^ksb^k = a^ks_qs_2 \ldots s_ts_{t+1}s_{t+2} \ldots b^k$, but, in order that $a^ksb^k \in L$ its two halves must be the same AND each half must start with $a^k$ and end with $b^k$, so must be $a^ksb^k = a^ks_qs_2 \ldots s_tb^ka^ks_{t+1}s_{t+2} \ldots b^k$, but, now $|a^ksb^k| = |a^ks_qs_2 \ldots s_tb^ka^ks_{t+1}s_{t+2} \ldots b^k| = k + t + k + k + t + k = 4k + 2t$, therefore $|a^ksb^k| = 4k+2t \ge 4k$. Is it right?

Comment: What do you think about it? Thanks!